# What does it mean for Magneto to be able to deflect rays from nuclear explosions?

Tags: marvel, x-men

In [a scientific explanation of Magneto’s powers](http://www.magnetowasright.com/pages/analysis/the-science-of-magneto.php) one sentence states that he can reflect the x-rays and gamma rays produced by nuclear explosions.

> Magneto’s ability to manipulate electromagnetic energies is not merely limited to magnetism and electricity. He has also shown control over most of the electromagnetic spectrum. The electromagnetic spectrum is the collection of various radiations that stem from EM energy, having properties of both electricity and magnetism in motion, specifically in varying frequencies of oscillation, or size and speed of waves. These energies are: radio waves, microwaves, terahertz radiation, infrared, visible light, ultraviolet, x-rays, and gamma rays. Ergo Magneto can generate or manipulate radio signals, generate heat (Uncanny X-Men #104), sense heat signatures, manipulate light to make himself invisible (Vision and the Scarlet Witch miniseires Vol. 1 #4), use UV energy to break chemical bonds (though he usually used his own power over the magnetic fields within atoms to do so), and reflect the x-rays and gamma rays produced by nuclear explosions (X-Men Vol. 2 #1, X-Men Vol 2 #86).

What does that mean, and what does that allow him to do?

Thank you.

Comment: Where did you read this scientific explanation?

Comment: @phantom42 - oh come on. It's the first hit on Google for Magneto + X-Rays :) http://www.magnetowasright.com/pages/analysis/the-science-of-magneto.php

Comment: i know lol , i apologize guys I'm scientifically illiterate so you guys are going to have to go easy on me

Comment: “I'll also follow that with a question about the description of his powers and just how much he can utilize his powers.” — Then you’ll want to do that as a separate question. One question per question please.

Comment: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/50376/can-magneto-control-light-as-well Refer this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

X-Rays and Gamma Rays are both electromagnetic radiation (as is visible light :) - they merely have different energies/wavelength. Reference: Wikipedia or basic Physics textbook.

As such, they are presumably within plausible control by Magneto whose powers are to control electromagnetic radiation in general.

Comment: So what could he destroy with these powers? Or control. Could you give me an example of what he could do with electromagnetic radiation?

Comment: @AaronTuturro - that's a separate question from "what does it mean"

Comment: sorry, could you help me rephrase that?

Comment: That means some writer broke Magneto. If he can control the entire em spectrum, that means Noone could ever defeat him. He could de power the hulk. Ugh.

Comment: What could magneto do if he could control half of an em spectrum

Comment: @dvk are you still there?